# How to store graph as an networkx.classes.graph.Graph object?

Tags: python, networkx

I am quite new to `Networkx`, so I am experimenting with its various graphing functions and would like to store the generated graph as an `networkx.classes.graph.Graph` object for further processing, something in the format of `<networkx.classes.graph.Graph at xxxxxxxxxxxxxx>` as appears on Python output.

Suppose I am using this following code to generate a bipartite graph:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G1 = nx.Graph()

G1.add_edges_from([('Frida','The Shawshank Redemption'), ('Pablo','The Shawshank Redemption'), ('Vincent','The Shawshank Redemption'), ('Joan', 'Forrest Gump'), ('Lee', 'Forrest Gump'), ('Andy', 'The Matrix'), ('Frida', 'The Matrix'), ('Pablo', 'The Matrix'),
('Andy', 'Anaconda'), ('Claude', 'Anaconda'), ('Georgia', 'Anaconda'), ('Frida', 'The Social Network'), ('Vincent', 'The Social Network'),
('Vincent', 'The Godfather'), ('Claude', 'Monty Python and the Holy Grail'), ('Georgia', 'Monty Python and the Holy Grail'), ('Claude', 'Snakes on a Plane'), ('Georgia', 'Snakes on a Plane'),
('Joan', 'Kung Fu Panda'), ('Lee', 'Kung Fu Panda'), ('Pablo', 'The Dark Knight'), 
('Andy', 'Mean Girls'), ('Joan', 'Mean Girls'), ('Lee', 'Mean Girls')])

l, r = nx.bipartite.sets(G1)
pos = {}

# Update position for node from each group
pos.update((node, (1, index)) for index, node in enumerate(l))
pos.update((node, (2, index)) for index, node in enumerate(r))

nx.draw(G1, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The last two lines of code will generate this graph:
[image]

This, however, is not a `networkx.classes.graph.Graph` object.

How can I save my graphing output as an `networkx.classes.graph.Graph` object, so that Python can read this object as such (and be able to retrieve the number of nodes and edges as well as other attributes from such object)?

Thank you.

Comment: What? This embedding/visualization is not a graph (a graph does not have absolute positions). This is not possible imho (if you want to treat this representation as a graph). Just work with the original graph-object (or in your case: ```l``` + ```r```).

Comment: So how can I do that?

Comment: Do what? You did not provide any info on what you want to do.

Comment: Store the graphing object into an networkx.classes.graph.Graph object.

Comment: I already said: a graph-embedding is not a graph! So get rid of that idea and think more of your task itself.

Comment: Or do I simply save the 'G'?

Comment: We don't know what you want to do. Save G and embed when you need it, or save (plt.savefig()) the embedded image itself (losing information about the original graph; it's just an image then).

Comment: So what constitutes an networkx.classes.graph.Graph object? Can Python infer from such object to know that, say, in my case, this network is a 19 nodes, 24 edges bipartite network?

Comment: Please work through the docs. 10 seconds of googling will lead to [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.bipartite.html): ```NetworkX does not have a custom bipartite graph class but the Graph() or DiGraph() classes can be used to represent bipartite graphs. However, you have to keep track of which set each node belongs to, and make sure that there is no edge between nodes of the same set. The convention used in NetworkX is to use a node attribute named “bipartite” with values 0 or 1 to identify the sets each node belongs to.```

Comment: Got it. I read (halfway) through the documentation and now have some grasps of the so-called `networkx.classes.graph.Graph` object. Thanks for clarifying this.